# Categorizing Debian Linux VPS

Tags: non-root-user, access-control, migration, file-management, multiuser

I like to Categorize or Divide one Debian VPS for different Tasks and Testing.

For Example two Apache Web Servers with no any connection between both. Something like installing apache2 web server only to user A and the user B can't even watch or check the user A apache webserver without access while user B can run a seperate apache server.

The purpose for this is in case I want to migrate user A Web Server and Configurations to new seperate vps without any hindrance to user B data, databases and configuration, securely.

I think my requirements are clear.

Eventhough, I just said I want divide maintain migrate user seperately, I don't how to do any of them. I am just new to linux and I think I can get a detailed answer on my question.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe use virtual hosts, see e.g. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found containerization such as docker and podman will suite my needs.